# How can i create a constant stream of bullets?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have recently started learning javascript with Codecademy. To extend my knowledge and just for fun, I followed HTML5 game tutorials by Gyrostorm: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL290A4D2398C97186/.

Now I completed the tutorial to make my version of his game, but I want it to be so that when you hold the spacebar, bullets fire at a certain rate. Currently, you have to keep pressing the spacebar to fire. I have a Jet.shoot function and a Jet.checkShoot function but after trying many times to setIntervals and setTimeouts nothing would work! Please help!

```
Jet.prototype.checkShooting = function() {
    if(this.isSpacebar && !this.isShooting) {
        this.isShooting = true;
        this.bullets[this.currentBullet].fire(this.noseX, this.noseY)
        this.currentBullet++;
        if(this.currentBullet >= this.bullets.length) {
            this.currentBullet = 0;
        }
    } else if(!this.isSpacebar) {
        this.isShooting = false;
    }
};

Jet.prototype.shoot = function() {
    this.isShooting = true;
    this.bullets[this.currentBullet].fire(this.noseX, this.noseY);
    this.currentBullet++;
    if(this.currentBullet >= this.bullets.length) {
        this.currentBullet = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is a live version of what I have so far: https://googledrive.com/host/0B2Xb6VzofFX-OGxEcnV3OUNTdFU/index.html

Thanks!

Comment: you should use onkeydown and onkeyup to active/disable the shoot function

Comment: @llnk I have this in the beginning on the script. Onkeydown sets isSpacebar to true and onkeyup sets it to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a given fire-rate, you need to handle the time. So best thing is to have a game-time, but anyway you need to implement a solution like this (i used real-world time (Date.now()) for this example) :

```
if(this.isSpacebar && Date.now()>this.shootPossibleTime) {
    this.shootPossibleTime =Date.now()+this.reloadTimeForThisWeapon;
    this.bullets[this.currentBullet].fire(this.noseX, this.noseY)
    this.currentBullet++;
    if(this.currentBullet >= this.bullets.length) {
        this.currentBullet = 0;
    }
}
```